# Hostinger error 500 - Como detectar o problema

Tags: php

Estou utilizando a hospedagem da Hostinger para hospedar minha aplicação, porém, a mesma não está funcionando e me retorna o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso saber o que está acontecendo com meu site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em pesquisas que fiz, isto pode ser problema em algum código PHP, e para detectar preciso de um log dos erros que estão ocorrendo.

Para solucionar, segui o tutorial desta página:
https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-verificar-os-logs-de-erro-php-do-seu-site/#1o-Passo-Habilitar-os-Logs-de-Erro

> Para habilitar os logs de erros você vai ter que adicionar a seguinte
>   linha ao arquivo:
>
> `php_flag log_errors on`
>
> Então vamos ter que determinar um local para que os logs sejam
>   armazenados. Para nosso exemplo criamos o arquivo error_log.txt no
>   diretório public_html. Para que os logs sejam armazenados no arquivo
>   criado, insira a seguinte linha no .htaccess:
>
> `php_value error_log /home/usuario_FTP/public_html/error_log.txt`
>
> NOTA:
>   Não esqueça de trocar usuario_FTP pelo seu usuário. Na Hostinger o
>   padrão é a letra “u” seguida por 9 dígitos numerais. Exemplo:
>   u497135640.
>
> Com estas configurações os logs de erro serão armazenados no arquivo error_log.txt localizado na pasta public_html.

Com isso o log me apresentou o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]